# When using Get Commit API in Azure devops between 2 datetimes it returns more results than expected?

Tags: git, azure, powershell, rest

I'm trying to get a set of work-items associated with some commits made between two dates on azure devops. The API that I'm using to retrieve these work-items is the following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?tabs=HTTP

This is the URL I'm using to get the set of commits:

```
"https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repository/commits?searchCriteria.fromDate=$baselineCommitDate&searchCriteria.toDate=$latestCommitDate&searchCriteria.includeWorkItems=$true&api-version=6.1-preview.1"
```

The variables in the URL are PowerShell variables and are the following:
`$organization`,
`$project`,
`$repository`,
`$baselineCommitDate`,
and `$latestCommitDate`

It's worth noting that the dates need to be American formatted i.e. MM/DD/YYYY like the following example 06/12/2023 12:41 PM is the 12th of June 2023.

Anyway, when I try and run this API call in a Powershell script with the variables populated I'm getting more results than expected. Between the dates I specified and the present I was getting 100 results when I should have been getting 60.

Has anyone else had trouble working with this API?

Answer (score 0):

**Note**:

- Given that the docs do not *describe* the required format and only provide *examples*, it is unclear whether the difference described in the next section matters. (If someone knows where a description can be found, let us know.)
- *Conceivably* - and hopefully (I cannot verify this myself) - a *different* date/time format is (also) accepted, such as an *international*, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)-based one, as used in the JSON *responses* (e.g., `2018-06-15T17:06:53Z`)

  - To that end, you need to explicitly call `.ToUniversalTime().ToString('u').Replace(' ', 'T')` on your `[datetime]` instances to produce the desired string format based on the [standard `u` format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-universal-sortable-u-format-specifier).
  - A simplified example (note the need to enclose the chained method calls in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)):

    ```bash
    "...Date=$($baselineCommitDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString('u').Replace(' ', 'T'))"
    ```

---

- As you state, the [examples in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?tabs=HTTP#in-a-date-range) suggests that a US-English date/time string format should be used, e.g. `7/3/2023 9:44:29 AM`
- However, note that PowerShell's *string interpolation*, i.e. embedding variable references in `"..."` (an [expandable string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)) does *not* use this format:

  - PowerShell's string interpolation is *culture-invariant*: it uses the rules of [`[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), which while *based* on the US-English culture, has some differences, notably using a *24-hour* time format instead of using the `AM` / `PM` suffixes, and using 2-digit, `0`-padded month and day numbers in the default format.
  - To produce the US-English format, call `.ToString([cultureinfo] 'en-US')` on a `[datetime]` instance, as the following example shows:

    ```bash
    $baselineCommitDate = Get-Date
    "
    String interpolation: $baselineCommitDate
    vs. 
    US-English format:    $($baselineCommitDate.ToString([cultureinfo] 'en-US'))
    "
    ```

    - This outputs something like:

      ```bash
      String interpolation: 07/03/2023 10:01:22
      vs. 
      US-English format:    7/3/2023 10:01:22 AM
      ```